# MSBuild.exe - set Company, Product name and Description with /p parameters

Tags: devops, .net-assembly, msbuild-task

We have a DevOps Pipeline where we use 'Visual Studio Build' task. We've added some /p parameter to populate Copyright, Assembly Version and File Version.

It looks like this:
[image]

As you see, we could set the following properties:

- /p:Version="1.2.3.4"
- /p:FileVersion="4.3.2.1"
- /p:Copyright="Copyright © Halli Galli Ltd."

This all works fine for .NET Core 6.0 and .NET Standard 2.x Assemblies.

But, we don't know the /p parameters for 'Product Name' and 'Description'.
So basically we're missing this properties (red):

[image]

What are the msbuild.exe /p parameters for the missing properties? We tried various hints from the web, but these we didn't figure out, neither we found a proper help page explaining the /p parameters of msbuild.exe

If you can tell ... - that would be great ;)

**Edit** : One of the missing properties was found, for 'Product Name' simply use '/p:Product' - kind of silly that we did not test with that. Remains 'Description'. And I got a little bit courious if this property even can be set at all ...